# Alternative proofs to inequality problems

Tags: real-analysis

I am working on an inequality problem from analysis textbook by Stephen C. Lay as follow:

> For $x, y \in \mathbb R$, show that $||x| - |y|| \leq |x - y|$.

The solution manual uses two elegant tricks of triangle inequality: $$|x| = |(x-y)+y| \leq |x-y|+|y|\  \\ |y|=|(y-x)+x|\leq |y-x|+|x|,$$ to arrive at a short elegant proof. But trickery is very hard for a beginner to master. I came up instead with these two *dumber* proofs and I would love to know if they are valid -- thank you very much for your time.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The first solution uses proof by contradiction. The negation of the problem is $||x|-|y||>|x-y|$.  I am going to use the induction-proven proposition in the same textbook that states: For all $n \in \mathbb N$, if $y > x > 0$, then $y^n > x^n$. And additionally the facts that $(|x|)^2 = (x)^2$ and $|x|\cdot|y| \geq xy$.

Here we have

$$\begin{align}
(||x|-|y||)^2 &> (|x-y|)^2\\
(|x|-|y|)^2 &> (x-y)^2\\
(|x|)^2 - 2 |x| \cdot |y| + (|y|)^2 &> x^2 -2xy +y^2 \\
- 2 |x| \cdot |y| &> -2xy\\
|x| \cdot |y| &< xy\\
\end{align}$$
which is contradictory to $|x|\cdot|y| \geq xy$.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The second solution uses proof by exhaustion of 4 cases: Both $x, y$ are positive, both negative, and one is positive and the other negative.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Again thank you for your times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both look like perfectly good methods, and not too complicated either. But you'll want to familiarize yourself with that sort of trickery with the triangle inequality, since it comes in handy often. Also, since the statement to be proven is a sort of backwards version of the triangle inequality, it's natural to prove it from the regular triangle inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Yes, to be sure I would love to master that trickery but it takes lots of time and practice; hopefully I will get it some day in near future. Thank you again and sorry for being a bit late.

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach, of squaring both sides, is pretty clever (and may be regarded as trickery in its own right). You can even use this approach to prove directly, not by contradiction: Start with the fact $|x|\cdot|y|\ge xy$, proceed to $\left(|x|-|y|\right)^2\le(x-y)^2$, and then take square roots of both sides.

Comment: Thank you for your nice words of encouragement and advice on techniques of proof. I am sorry for being a bit late. Thank you again.